# Measure of the set $\{x\in [0,1]: \text{the decimal expansion of } x \text{ contains infinitely many 7.} \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I got this question in an old qualifier exam of Real analysis. Let $A$ be the set of all real numbers in the closed interval $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains infinitely many 7. Find the Lebesgue measure of the set $A.$

(Now ownward when I say a number, it is supposed to be in the unit interval.)
If I define $A_i$ to be the set of all those numbers whose decimal expansion has a $7$ at the $i$th place. It is clear that the set $A$ in the question is limit supremum of all $A_i$. And, I can show that $A_i$ are independent event (Lebesgue measure restricted to the unit interval is a probability measure). We next observe that 
$$\sum |A_i| = \infty.$$
An application of second Borel-Cantelli’s lemma therefore gives that the measure of $A$ is 1.

My problem is that the notion of independence is a probabilistic notion (and not introduced in most real analysis classes). So, I am interested in a more direct (say, analytical?) approach to this problem.

While writing this question this thought came to mind that I want something along the following line: Try showing that the set of all numbers whose decimal expansion has only finitely many $7$ appearing has a measure 0. In order to do so, we first obeserve that there are only countably many finite subsets of natural number. So if for a fixed finite subset $F$ of natural numbers, I can show that the set of numbers which has 7 only at those locations specified by the set $F$ has measure 0, then I will be done. Any thought on this? Would this work or not? Any alternate approach is also a welcome?

Meanwhile I will try the above idea and update accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Write 0.7** where ** is any sequence made up of 0, 1. This is already an uncountable set of numbers which contains 7 only once and that too at the first place.

Comment: Sorry, sloppy thinking

Comment: But it is the right track to be on (eta: as bitesizebo demonstrates). What is the measure of the points with #7s = 0? #7s=1? Or, more simply, what is the measure of points where the last 7 is seen in the nth position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach to atone for my sins above.

Let $N$ be the set of numbers in $I$ that have no $7$s in their expansion. I claim that
$mN =0$.

Let $N_{d_1,...,d_n}$ be the set of numbers in $N$ that start with digits $d_1,...,d_n$.
Hopefully it is clear that $m N_{d_1,...,d_n} = {1 \over 10^n} mN$.
 Since $N = \cup_{d \neq 7} N_d$, we have $m N = {9 \over 10} m N$ and so $m N =0$.

It follows that $m N_{d_1,...,d_n} = 0$ and so $m (\cup_{d_1,...,d_n} N_{d_1,...,d_n}) = 0 $. Finally, $m (\cup_n \cup_{d_1,...,d_n} N_{d_1,...,d_n}) = 0$.

Hence the set of numbers that have a finite number of $7$s in their expansion is a null set.

Answer (score 3):

This feels very similar to the Cantor set, and copper.hat's statement can be amended and used. This I think is similar to the method you are proposing. We wish to show the measure of the set of numbers with *finitely* many 7's in it's decimal expansion (call this set $C$) is 0.

Let $C_n$ be the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ with no 7's past the first n digits of it's decimal expansion. Then $C = \cup_n C_n$ thus to show $\mu(C) = 0$ it suffices to show $\mu(C_n) = 0$ for all $n$ (where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure).

But $C_n$ has a close relation to the Cantor set. For each $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}^n$ let $C_{x_1, \ldots, x_n}$ be the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ with decimal expansion $0.x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \cdots$ where there are no $7$'s past the $n$th digit $x_n$. The Cantor set is the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ which have no 2's in their ternary expansion. We show the Cantor set has measure 0 by showing it is the intersection of sets with measure going to 0. The same technique can be used to show that $C_{x_1, \ldots, x_n}$ has measure 0.

Thus while $C_n$ is uncountable, $C_n = \bigcup_{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}^n} C_{x_1, \ldots, x_n}$ is a countable union of sets of measure 0 and hence has measure 0 as required.

Comment: Let $C_{...}$ be the set of numbers with *binary* expansion - binary should be decimal.

Comment: @daw Thanks, corrected